# Parametrizing LinkedList with '?' in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am new to some of the in-built data structures in JAVA and observed while playing around with LinkedList that this code does not raise an error :

```
LinkedList<?> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Can anyone please explain me how can we have this as a valid declaration ? I am using Eclipse and it does not show any errors upon initialization. Adding elements after this, however, does not work in this case.

Comment: Why do you think it should be invalid?

Comment: so interesting. even when you dimanod inference it works. you should add this like LinkedList<?> list = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it seems it is valid but why ?

Comment: @KickButtowski That is kind of purpose of `<?>`, to accept any type like in this case `<Integer>`.

Comment: I am not too sure. I searched for what '?' means while parametrizing in JAVA, but only got results like - "Learn LinkedList" etc. Guess my search has been personalized. Also, I thought maybe **LinkedList<T>** is the same as **LinkedList<?>** but that too is not correct as in the former, insertion is possible. So what does '?' actually do ?

Comment: You need to search for wildcards: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: @Pshemo it seems it just accept Integer cuz when I use dimaond inference it shows the line is looking for Integer type

Comment: @KickButtowski - It is again a valid declaration but insertion is not possible.

Comment: @Noob I know but it is more interesting that what type it is in the right side?

Comment: are you asking me? cuz I am just trying to learn here :)

Comment: @KickButtowski It is empty in your case and Integer in my case.

Comment: @Noob make it interesting and get rid of Integer :) +1 cuz it is interesting question to me

Comment: @KickButtowski - Done that , no changes.

Comment: @Noob Insertion *is* possible. You can only insert `null`, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
LinkedList<?> list;
```

you are declaring a variable named `list` of type `LinkedList` and providing the wildcard `?` as a type argument to be bound to `LinkedList`'s type parameter `T`. So `list` will be of type `LinkedList<?>`. This wildcard `?` will capture some type, but **that type will be unknown and unusable.**

This

```
new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

is an instance creation expression. You are creating an instance of type `LinkedList` while providing a type argument of type `Integer` to be bound to `LinkedList`'s type parameter `T`. The type of the instance creation expression will therefore be `LinkedList<Integer>`.

Note that you will be interacting with the created `LinkedList` through the variable `list` of type `LinkedList<?>`. So regardless of what type argument you used to create it, you are now looking at it through a value of type `LinkedList<?>`.

Now, you can assign a value of type `LinkedList<Integer>` to a variable of type `LinkedList<?>` because `LinkedList<?>` is a super type of `LinkedList<Integer>`. We can go into detail about why this is the case, but the rules are described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2).

---

As for

```
LinkedList<?> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

the notation `<>` denotes that the type argument for the instance creation expression should be inferred. [The rules for type inferences are numerous and complex.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) Basically, since `?` denotes an unknown type, the only thing we can be sure about is that the type argument should be at least `Object` since that is the supertype of all types. And therefore that becomes the type inferred.

Answer (score 1):

`?` as a generic parameter basically means "any class" and `Integer` definitely qualifies as "any class", hence no error. There are not errors during initialization because generics are not present during runtime so what type of generic you have does not matter once the code compiles (*almost* doesn't matter)

Comment: how do you explain this? LinkedList<?> list1 = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: what is the type here?

Comment: @KickButtowski `<>` in Java 1.7 is just a syntax sugar forcing the compiler to guess the generic type based on the context. In this case it will become LinkedList<?> list1 = new LinkedList<?>(), which is correct syntax.

Comment: No, it won't. You cannot use `?` as a type argument in an instance creation expression. `Object` will be inferred and bout to `LinkedList`'s type parameter.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are correct, silly me... Anyhow, the type of the `<>` is going to be `Object` in this case.